# Storing array chunkles in variables

Tags: php, arrays

I used `array_chunk` to divide my array into pieces.

This is my array structure now:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 10
            [2] => 100
            [3] => 101
            [4] => 102
            [5] => 103
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 104
            [1] => 105
            [2] => 106
            [3] => 107
            [4] => 108
            [5] => 109
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11
            [1] => 110
            [2] => 111
            [3] => 112
            [4] => 113
            [5] => 114
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 115
            [1] => 116
            [2] => 117
            [3] => 118
            [4] => 119
            [5] => 12
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => 120
            [1] => 121
            [2] => 122
            [3] => 123
            [4] => 124
            [5] => 125
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [0] => 126
            [1] => 127
            [2] => 128
            [3] => 129
            [4] => 13
            [5] => 130
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [0] => 131
            [1] => 132
            [2] => 133
            [3] => 134
            [4] => 135
            [5] => 136
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => 137
            [1] => 138
            [2] => 139
            [3] => 14
            [4] => 140
            [5] => 141
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => 142
            [1] => 143
            [2] => 144
            [3] => 145
            [4] => 146
            [5] => 147
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => 148
            [1] => 149
            [2] => 15
            [3] => 150
            [4] => 151
            [5] => 152
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [0] => 153
            [1] => 154
            [2] => 155
            [3] => 156
            [4] => 157
            [5] => 158
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [0] => 159
            [1] => 16
            [2] => 160
            [3] => 161
            [4] => 162
            [5] => 163
        )

    [12] => Array
        (
            [0] => 164
            [1] => 165
            [2] => 166
            [3] => 167
            [4] => 168
            [5] => 169
        )

    [13] => Array
        (
            [0] => 17
            [1] => 170
            [2] => 171
            [3] => 172
            [4] => 173
            [5] => 174
        )

    [14] => Array
        (
            [0] => 175
            [1] => 176
            [2] => 178
            [3] => 18
            [4] => 19
            [5] => 2
        )

    [15] => Array
        (
            [0] => 20
            [1] => 21
            [2] => 22
            [3] => 23
            [4] => 28
            [5] => 29
        )

    [16] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 31
            [3] => 32
            [4] => 33
            [5] => 34
        )

    [17] => Array
        (
            [0] => 35
            [1] => 36
            [2] => 37
            [3] => 38
            [4] => 39
            [5] => 4
        )

    [18] => Array
        (
            [0] => 40
            [1] => 41
            [2] => 42
            [3] => 43
            [4] => 44
            [5] => 45
        )

    [19] => Array
        (
            [0] => 46
            [1] => 47
            [2] => 48
            [3] => 49
            [4] => 5
            [5] => 50
        )

    [20] => Array
        (
            [0] => 51
            [1] => 6
            [2] => 69
            [3] => 7
            [4] => 8
            [5] => 86
        )

    [21] => Array
        (
            [0] => 87
            [1] => 88
            [2] => 89
            [3] => 9
            [4] => 90
            [5] => 91
        )

    [22] => Array
        (
            [0] => 92
            [1] => 93
            [2] => 94
            [3] => 95
            [4] => 96
            [5] => 97
        )

    [23] => Array
        (
            [0] => 98
            [1] => 99
        )
)
```

How can I store every of 24 arrays into its own variable so I can access elements of that array easily on the webpage later?

I want something like this (the numbers are based on the numbers given in the array above):

```
$array1 = array(1,10,100,101,102,103);
$array2 = array(104,105,106,107,108,109);
```

Can somebody please help me and write a function that does something like this (so to input chunked array and then store every chunk in its own variable)?

-----UPDATE-----

Everything works fine now, but I noticed a small problem.

The function that I use:

```
<?php

function gallery_1()
{
    $picture_ids = array(   1,10,100,101,102,103,
                            104,105,106,107,108,109,
                            11,110,111,112,113,114,
                            115,116,117,118,119,12,
                            120,121,122,123,124,125,
                            126,127,128,129,13,130,
                            131,132,133,134,135,136,
                            137,138,139,14,140,141,
                            142,143,144,145,146,147,
                            148,149,15,150,151,152,
                            153,154,155,156,157,158,
                            159,16,160,161,162,163,
                            164,165,166,167,168,169,
                            17,170,171,172,173,174,
                            175,176,178,18,19,2,
                            20,21,22,23,28,29,
                            3,30,31,32,33,34,
                            35,36,37,38,39,4,
                            40,41,42,43,44,45,
                            46,47,48,49,5,50,
                            51,6,69,7,8,86,
                            87,88,89,9,90,91,
                            92,93,94,95,96,97,
                            98,99);

    $n = 6;  // number of pictures in each row

    echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($picture_ids); $i++) 
    {
        // start a new row after each $n pictures
        if (($i > 0) && ($i % $n === 0)) 
        {
            echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
            echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
        }

        echo '<article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<a href="images/originals/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" alt="" /></a>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '</article>' . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```

You can see it in action here: http://aleksvujic.eu/gallery1.php

But if I insert same images but without the PHP function (bare HTML code) it looks like this http://aleksvujic.eu/gallery_eng.php (notice that there aren't white spaces between images like on first link!)

Can anyone help me how to fix this? :)

Comment: Why do you want to separate them into several variables? Accessing the elements is already easy: `echo $array[2][3];` will print `112`.

Comment: Because I want to write a function which returns as many variables containing 6 numbers as there are arrays. It's much easier for me to use this.

Comment: I find it hard to think of a case where that will be easier, because then you need to keep track on an unknown number of variables (arrays). However, if it is really what you want, the answer from @ciro should do the job...

Comment: In general: in PHP it is not possible for a function to return more than one variable. (it _can_ return an array, but then you end up with the same array as you had before...)

Comment: So you advise me to use echo $array[2][3]?

Comment: Actually, yes. It is the easiest way to reference the elements. Note that the first number (2 in this example) references the third sub-array (the one with values 11, 110, 111, 112, 113 and 114) and the second number (3 in this example) references the fourth number in that sub-array (112).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the elaboration in your 'answer' correctly, you want to create a gallery of pictures with many rows of six pictures each. In that case, you perhaps do not need to chuck the array. Instead, the following php also solves this:

```
$picture_ids = array(
    1, 10, 100, 101, 102, 103,
    104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109,
    11, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114
    // and as many more as needed, in the order you specify
);

$n = 6;  // number of pictures in each row

echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
for ($i = 0; $i < count($picture_ids); $i++) {
    // start a new row after each $n pictures
    if (($i > 0) && ($i % $n === 0)) {
        echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
        echo '<div class="row">' . PHP_EOL;
    }

    echo '<article class="6u 12u$(xsmall) work-item" style="width: 40%;">' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '<a href="images/originals/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" class="image fit thumb"><img src="images/thumbs_large/' . $picture_ids[$i] . '.jpg" alt="" /></a>' . PHP_EOL;
    echo '</article>' . PHP_EOL;
}
echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
```

Does this help out?

(small note: if you write html (not xhtml), you do not need to end the `<img ...>` tag with a slash)

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! For future questions: it might be helpful to take one step back and explain in the question what you want to achieve (and then tell what you tried so far). That way, it is easier to give a helpfull anser to the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $newName = "array".($key+1);
        $$newName = $value;
}
```

$array is result of array_chunk operation

Answer (score 0):

So you mean something like this?

```
<?php

function gallery($array)
{
    $chunk = array_chunk($array, 6);

    foreach($chunk as $key => $value)
    {
        $newName = "array".($key+1);
        $$newName = $value;
    }

    return $value;

}

?>
```

Comment: No. This will not work, since the new variables will not be accessible outside of the function. AFAIK, you can not do that in a function if you do not know in advance how many arrays the function will create. (and then you will need the `global` keyword to tell the function about these arrays)